# Android Studio - How to get data from an EditText in a RecyclerView and put them into an ArrayList in the main activity?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I have a RecyclerView consisting of EditTexts that uses an ArrayList as its data set, when the EditTexts are edited I want that ArrayList to be updated as well and I want to be able to use it in the Main Activity currently I've tried implementing a TextChangedListener however I have no clue how to get the data and transfer it to my list. Here's the code:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public ArrayList playerList;
private Button runItButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playerList = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        playerList.add("Player " + (i + 1));
    }

    runItButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonStartGame);
    runItButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrinktasksActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("playerList", playerList);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclyerViewNames);
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, playerList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}


public void addPlayers(View view){
    playerList.add("Player " + (playerList.size() + 1));
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

The adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList playerList;

public MyAdapter(Context ct, List players){
    context = ct;
    playerList = (ArrayList) players;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_name, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String current = playerList.get(position).toString();
    holder.editText.setHint(current);

    holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // The code I assume should go here but I don't know how to implement

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return playerList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    EditText editText;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editname);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I can tell how to pass data from adapter to main-class. But in addTextChangedListener this will call that function each time when text change. What exactly you want?

Comment: I would like the ArrayList to consist of the data that is in the editTexts if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to implement a custom callback to your activity with the index in which the edittext is edited and what is the new text.

**Create a callback interface inside adapter**

```
    public interface TextChangeCallback {
        void textChangedAt(int position, String text);
    }
```

**Pass the inteface implementation to Adapter via constructor**

```
public MyAdapter(Context ct, List players,TextChangeCallback callback){
    context = ct;
    playerList = (ArrayList) players;
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

**Trigger callback to activity whenever you edit the text using TextWatcher**

```
holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.equals("")){
                    return;
                }
                data.set(position, String.valueOf(s));
                callback.textChangedAt(position, String.valueOf(s));

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

**Add this interface implementation to your adapter**

```
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, playerList, new MyAdapter.TextChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void textChangedAt(int position, String text) {
                playerList.set(position, text);
                Log.d("UPDATED LIST : ", String.valueOf(data));
            }
        });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

This will now update the ArrayList in adapter and activity as you edit the edittext from recyclerview.

You can find the complete implementation from [this link](https://github.com/kariot/edittext-recyclerview)